# Outlook add on redirects to browser

Tags: azure, graph, outlook, single-sign-on, outlook-web-addins

We have a site used by Outlook addin hosted on sharepoint, when a user tried to access it they had a browser window open on the Sharepoint Online site, our front end is hosted there but it doesn't bring us to site location it just brings to Sharepoint home page.

We resolved this for a lot of users by adding runtimes in our manifest (this will force Outlook to use IE, whereas before browser is determined on a combination of 365 and windows versions). Still for some users it will bring us to a new browser, we have checked they are on the same Windows and Office 365 version as others who have the plugin working in Outlook task pane.

Also to note there is no issue with anyone using the plugin from OWA (web mail in a browser) and the redirect from desktop outlook looks like it for SSO then verifies user in browser and brings us to Sharepoint.

anyone have any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: Are the Outlook addin a VSTO addin or a web addin (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/office-add-ins)? Is it possible to include a screen shot that shows the full add-in pane as well as the error?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, we have a manifest file so I guess that means its a web addin? So the full add-in pane doesn't actually load when we see this error it just redirects to an external browser and the error above is displayed. This is something to do with SSO we think but finding it really hard to debug the issue, especially since it is only happening for some users none of which are developers.@OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT

Comment: For web addins, The addin page and its resources (html/js/etc) should be accessible by the webview. As you noted, the addin can work if the webview can access the resources, but how that access is provided in your setup depends on your setup and addin host (SharePoint in your case). The addin platform does not have SharePoint logic to sign user into SharePoint. Have you checked with the addin developer or vendor?

Comment: We are developing the addin, we have no problem accessing the Sharepoint from OWA, most users have no problem accessing Sharepoint from Addin, but some users can only access from OWA and get the no client ID error and an external browser launched from Desktop version, so they should have access if they can reach from OWA right?

Comment: I think it should be possible.

Comment: You think what should be possible @CarlZhao

Comment: The above error is telling that the related that the Application (client) ID that the "Azure portal – App registrations experience" assigned to your app is missing. Validate the token in https://jwt.ms and see if it contains the info or not.

Comment: For some reason now it is not giving that error but still is launching an external browser to sharepoint online homepage (our front end is hosted there but it brings us to the home page). No external browser should be launched, can't figure this out at all

Comment: Updated question and added a bounty

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT any chance you could take another look at updated question, we are very stuck on this.

Comment: Likely what is happening, is that authentication to the share point server is failing, and sharepoint is popping up a dialog when that error happens. The Add-ins WebView control, just needs to be able to access the website to load. Is it possible to enable anonymous access to your sharepoint site? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/manage-anonymous-access-for-a-web-application Or is there a way to configure sharepoint so that login takes place inside the taskpane instead of a pop out?

or host the add-in on a non-sharepoint webserver?

Comment: Can you also update with the versions of Office and Windows that you are seeing the bug on? (are you certain that this isn't different when you are seeing the bug) Screenshots / videos of the bug you are seeing may also help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I think we may have got this sorted now. We ran fiddler trace on one of the users machines who was seeing the issue. We collected all the domains from the trace (some of them were for our internal sso) and added them to the app domains in our manifest file. So far it seems to be working although do need to reach out to more users. I do appreciate you coming back and requesting further information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by any sites or domains trying to be accessed by outlook addin need to be added to app domains in the manifest file. We ran a fiddler trace on the users machine and took a list of the domains that were being hit (for SSO) once we added them this issue was resolved.